# In Wordpress, why update.php can't be reached?

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently I have installed WordPress 4.6 through 5-Minute installation. I can post something. Also, I can add plugins from WordPress Plugin Directory, but can't upload & install any new plugin from my PC; once I choose a plugin from there and click on "install now", then I will be directed to the  following URL:

> /wp-admin/update.php?action=upload-plugin

But I get following error:

> This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset. Try: Checking the
>   connection Checking the proxy and the firewall

I have reinstalled my WP, no other plugins have been installed and I'm using the default template of WP. Also, I have given 777 permission to all files. Whats the problem?

Comment: "Also, I have given 777 permission to all files." Ugh, please don't do that. File permissions are, among other things, a security feature.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right, it risks the security but I just wanna make it work, then I'll definitely change it!

Comment: What's your server type? Nginx? Apache? Do you have a firewall?

Comment: 777 permissions are _very bad_. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: Can you confirm if update/upload word is not blocked in your firewall?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch thanks for your answer. I'm using my university's servers. And sorry, I'm beginner so don't know exactly their server type. But they are using Linux servers. You can find more information on their wiki:
https://wiki.metropolia.fi/display/itservices/Home+Page,+Shell+and+MySQL+Services

Or, is there any why I can figure that out?

Comment: @VivekSrivastava Do you mean firewall on my PC? If so, I don't think it matters cause I'm using our university's servers. But if you mean their firewall, I don't know to check that. Can you please guide me?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Also, which permission do you recommend?

Comment: @Mahdi You can try going to any online Wordpress Demo website such as - http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-admin (admin/demo123) and try installing a new plugin. If you face the same issue then the problem is with your university's firewall.